# Confusion over graphs of potential

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, scattering, centrifugal-force

[image]

---

The above graph represents the effective potential that arises from the inverse square force law, irrelevant though for this question.

In a [pdf I found, p. 58-59](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/relativity/dynrel.pdf), where I have the following, the author describes events that would happen if a stationary particle was placed in any of the points (that is, any of the radii). Now, one of the points states that

> When $E \gt 0$. Now the particle can sit above the horizontal axis. It comes in from
> infinity, reaches some minimum distance $r$, then rolls back out to infinity.

Now, surely, we would always have a force $F=-\nabla V_{\text{eff}}$ which would provide acceleration for the particle, particularly, when the particle is in a point where $E \gt 0$, we would clearly have an acceleration of the particle away from the origin which is stated in the point mentioned, that is *"It comes in from infinity..."*, now, the part that confuses me is why it would ever *"...roll back out to infinity."* if there is clearly no reason to do so. I don't understand where I am going wrong here.

Comment: I need clarification.  I don't understand your difficulty.  Can you fill out your argument a bit?  What do you think should happen?   In particular, your thinking behind "there is clearly no reason to do so".

Comment: @garyp Sorry for not being concise enough, my issue is that under this potential, why would it ever tend to a maximal radius and come back? Surely what I would expect is that if the point is above the horizontal line, at any point, it would never have enough energy to "roll back to infinity", that is, $r \to 0$ (since Energy is conservative under any field where $F = -\nabla V$. Therefore, I would expect the particle to tend towards an infinite radius, but I know that's wrong because that goes against common sense, doesn't it?

Comment: Btw, I am not sure what he means by "minimum" radius, does he mean "maximum"?

Comment: I don't understand your point of view here, so I can't figure out what your conceptual stumbling block is.   I started writing a comment to explain *my* point of view, but it got too long, so I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange! I have looked at the reference you supplied (by the way it is image 58-59 not page 58-59, bu I got there!) and I think the choice of words under those three bullet points is unfortunate and is causing your confusion. Bullet point 1 ($E=E_{\rm min}$) is fine: the particle does indeed 'sit': it is in the radial direction constantly at $r=r_\star$. But in the other two cases the particle is *not* sitting, it is moving radially. In case two it is oscillating, and in case three it executes an unbounded radial motion.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that was not what I or the author meant. When he said "sitting", he implied dropping a particle that is stationary, of course, it would have to have radial velocity, at least, otherwise it would not be necessary to specify that this is an effective potential as in that case, $V_{\text{eff}} = V$

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized you said "unbounded radial motion", so would that be just me misunderstanding what he said and the particle's radius would tend to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

If $E>0$ and the object is coming in from the right, travelling to the left, at first it would feel a force of attraction ($F=-\nabla V$) causing the object to speed up.  It passes through the minimum of potential, and continues travelling to the left.  The slope of the potential changes sign as the object passes through, so the force becomes repulsive, and the object slows.   It slows and slows until it reaches the radius at which $E=V$.  All the energy is potential, so the kinetic energy is zero.  That radius is the minimum radius for energy $E$. The force is still repulsive, so the object turns around and starts to travel to the right. It speeds up until the potential minimum at which time the force becomes attractive and begins to slow the object.   Since the potential at infinity is zero, the energy far far away from the origin must be all kinetic.   That is to say, the object continues travelling to the right forever.  It slows, but never stops.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main issue I am having, everyone is saying that if $E \gt 0$, it starts from the right, but it should start from the left, since from the right $E$ cannot be bigger than $0$ as $E$ approaches $0$ as $r$ approaches infinity.

Comment: @Mathematics E = K+V$_{eff}$, so the classical particle cannot be on the left (negative kinetic energy?!). Also, when potentials are plotted versus $r$, it's usually for radially symmetric systems, so there is no negative $r$.

Comment: @BillN Why not? You are dropping a **stationary** particle with a radial value where $V_{\text{eff}}$ > 0, since it is **stationary**, it has no KE thereby the effective potential is the same as the energy, thereby the kinetic energy will never be negative. Also, I never mentioned negative $r$. Also, correction to my last comment, I meant to say $V_{\text{eff}}$ approaches $0$ as $r \to \infty$.

Comment: So, following this point, the particle should start to feel an outward force, that is $-\nabla V_{{\text{eff}}}$ which accelerates it outward. My question is, once more, why would it ever roll back such that its radius would start decreasing once again? Am I misunderstanding what the author meant? I am sorry if I am anything wrong.

Comment: If you start the particle where $E>0$ and $V>0$, then it will never roll back.  Note that the only place this occurs is near $r=0$.  If you start the particle where $E<0$ it will oscillate.  Note that in the latter case $E<0$ only if $V<0$.   If I had a blackboard, I could explain all this in 60 seconds.  Having only a static image is a challenge.

Comment: Concerning your first comment: "from the right E cannot be bigger than 0 " is not correct, and perhaps that's the crux of the issue.   Far to the right, $V\rightarrow 0$, but the particle can be moving, and hence have kinetic energy.   In that case $E=V+K= 0+K>0$

Comment: @garyp No need to explain it, and I totally get what you are saying, by the way, when I say $E>0$, I am implying dropping the particle in a radial position where $V_{\text{eff}} > 0$. I was thinking the same thing from the beginning, the particle never rolling back which totally makes sense. The only issue I had with this was that I cannot understand what the author was saying, his statement is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Also, this graph is similar to the graph representing the potential due to the law of gravity. Surely by this logic, any particle close to a massive body is thrown away from the body passively.

Comment: So all is good?

Comment: @garyp I still have the issue I described in the last comment, this is implying something that is not true.

Comment: But thank you for everything so far.

Answer (score 0):

The author does use some confusing language:

> $E >0$.   Now  the  particle  can  sit  above  the  horizontal  axis.   It  comes  in  from infinity,  reaches some minimum distance $r*$,  then rolls back out to infinity.  We will see later that, for the $V=−k/r$ potential, this trajectory is hyperbola.

1. Remember that the vertical axis is *energy*, not position, so when the author (poorly) uses the word "sit", he is describing a constant energy, not a zero velocity. His starting condition for the example is a large distance from the force center.
2. He is using polar coordinates because angular momentum is constant in the system, but the only coordinate shown is $r$. He is not showing how $\theta$ behaves.
3. If $\theta$ is constant, the angular momentum in his reference frame is zero, and $V_{eff}=-k/r$, and the $E_{min}$ dip doesn't occur! In that situation, the particle would not go "back out to infinity." BUT he is assuming, implied from his argument (orbits), that there is angular momentum.
4. The effective radial force direction is determined by the *negative* of the *slope* of $V_{eff}$. If the slope is positive with respect to $r$ ($r>r*$), the direction of the effective radial force is toward the origin. If the slope is negative, the direction of the force is away from the origin. This is independent of the value of $E$.

As a corollary of this, if the angular momentum is zero then the slope of the potential is always positive, so the force is always toward the origin and there is no orbit.

5. The only way to have $E>0$ in a gravitational system is for the particle to have kinetic energy. If there is no kinetic energy (your initial condition), $E=V=-k/r$.
6. When he uses the word "rolls" he is not describing a literal idea. Physics instructors often use the metaphor of a ball rolling along a surface shaped like $V_{eff}$ to describe what the motion might be, but it's not a literal trajectory along the curve. IMHO, this metaphor might work in a classroom setting, but isn't appropriate for a textbook due to the confusing language.

Based on comments you have made, it seems your confusion centers around the word "sit", and not realizing that the angular momentum must be non-zero in order to have the negative slope portion of the effective potential.

Comment: I get what you are saying, and I just realized what the author more than likely meant. He meant $E > 0$ such that we have an infinite $r$ approaching $0$, fair enough, I think the author meant to imply that $\theta$ behaves in a way such that $\dot{\theta} \neq 0$, thereby $E \neq -k/r$, but I get what you are saying. What I wanted to ask though was 2 questions: One being very, very stupid, but I just realized I don't actually understand the meaning of negative energy which I dismissed since I only cared about the difference of it. 2. What would then happen if you dropped the particle

Comment: at the left? Thank you.

Comment: @Mathematics You don't drop a particle at the left. For the definition of the graph, there is no $r<0$. All $r$ values are positive. $\theta$ can go $0$ to $2\pi$, and that's the whole plane. Take a look at [this link for polar coordinates][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system].  Also, the author is definitely discussing orbital motion, which means $\dot{\theta}\ne 0$.

Comment: You are misunderstanding me, when I said left, I didn't mean negative values, I meant beyond the point where E is positive, I know what polar coordinates are. Apart from that question, I also had the one I mentioned where I was asking why would energy ever be lower than 0?

Comment: Similar question for positive potential?

Comment: @Mathematics Classically, the total energy can't be less than the potential energy function. The kinetic energy is always non-negative. So you can't move to the left of the $V_{eff}$ curve. If $E=V_{eff}$ the particle is at rest, and there is no method to "place" the particle in a situation where $E<V_{eff}$.

$E<0$ is possible if $V_{eff}<0$. This is the situation for closed orbits with gravitational or electromagnetic forces.

Comment: Why can't you move left? Surely if $E > 0$, and the effective potential is positive,  it would be possible, that is to say, the potential would be positive, which I am once again asking if it is possible or not. It might be a stupid question, but I've been studying a lot of Maths and now I am becoming more and more intrigued in Physics and where I might have missed out a lot of information. So once again let me ask, is positive potential possible, and what does it mean to have negative energy?

Comment: @Mathematics E=K+V. If particle is left of the V curve, then K<0. That's it! K can't be negative, classically.

Comment: You keep repeating the same thing, sorry for saying, but that's not what I am asking, I am asking, literally, why is energy being defined as negative, what's the difference between "negative" energy and "positive"? Is it all standard of notation and energy is always defined as negative?

Comment: @Mathematics If your question is "How can total energy be negative?" that is different from what you asked originally. Post it as a new question.

Comment: Just did, so back to the question, of E = V, K does not need to be negative. Remember, this graph describes effective potential, thereby, why can't the particle be on the left?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what is bothering you exactly, but I would like to give my insights of how I understand this problem. I hope you find it helpful.

Firstly I want to point out that the effective potential here actually is the sum of good old gravitational P.E. and the contribution of the angular motion to the particle's total K.E. Which makes the effective K.E. in this case to be the radial contribution to the total K.E.

Now why is the Kinetic Energy split up in this way? well doing so what happens is that our analysis simply maps to that of a 1D point particle under the influence of the "defined effective potential" and the 1D coordinate mapping directly to the radial coordinate of our actual particle. When we included the angular K.E. into the effective P.E. we actually made use of conservation of angular momentum to get rid of angular motion components completely and get a term proportional to r^(-2). The math of these two scenarios are similar and hence can be treated equivalent. So, what we analyze from this graph is partial, just the radial part.The crucial thing to keep in mind is that our actual particle still has an angular motion component and it is going around the central source as well and not just up and down a radial line.

All the talk about sitting at a point, coming in from infinity and all that refers to the 1D analogue particle we introduced The actual particle's radial coordinate matches this 1D guy's coordinate while having a changing angular value. In effect, the actual trajectory is like swinging around the centre, coming in from an infinity and going away to another infinity at a different angular coordinate.